# Oracle 10.2.0.4.0 query on partial xpath

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath

I need to change the below query to be able to query any kind of tender item.

/Basket/**Card**TenderItem/Description

/Basket/**Cash**TenderItem/Description

So

/Basket/**Wildcard**TenderItem/Description

I have looked at various examples on but cannot them to bring back any results when running (happily admit to user error if can get working!)

```
SELECT 
RETURN_ID
,SALE_ID,
,extractValue(xmltype(RETURNxml),'/Basket/CashTenderItem/NetValue')
,extractValue(xmltype(RETURNxml),'/Basket/CashTenderItem/Description')
FROM SPR361
WHERE return_id = '9999.0303|20170327224954|2063'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to match anything the ends with `TenderItem`, but doesn't have anything after that, you could be specific with substring checks:

```
SELECT 
RETURN_ID
,SALE_ID
,extractValue(xmltype(RETURNxml),
  '/Basket/*[substring(name(), string-length(name()) - 9) = "TenderItem"]/NetValue')
,extractValue(xmltype(RETURNxml),
  '/Basket/*[substring(name(), string-length(name()) - 9) = "TenderItem"]/Description')
FROM SPR361
WHERE return_id = '9999.0303|20170327224954|2063'
```

If you never have any nodes with anything after that fixed string then @Shnugo's `contains` approach is easier, and in Oracle would be very similar:

```
...
,extractValue(xmltype(RETURNxml),
  '/Basket/*[contains(name(), "TenderItem")]/NetValue')
,extractValue(xmltype(RETURNxml),
  '/Basket/*[contains(name(), "TenderItem")]/Description')
```

I'm not sure there's any real difference between `name()` and `local-name()` here.

If a basket can have multiple child nodes (card and cash, or more than one of each) you could also switch to XMLTable syntax:

```
SELECT 
s.RETURN_ID
,s.SALE_ID
,x.netvalue
,x.description
FROM SPR361 s
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  '/Basket/*[contains(name(), "TenderItem")]'
  PASSING XMLType(s.RETURNxml)
  COLUMNS netvalue NUMBER PATH './NetValue'
  , description VARCHAR(80) PATh './Description'
) x
WHERE s.return_id = '9999.0303|20170327224954|2063'
```

And it's overkill here maybe, but for more complicated tests you can use other XPath syntax, like:

```
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  'for $i in /Basket/*
    where contains($i/name(), "TenderItem") return $i'
  PASSING XMLType(s.RETURNxml)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is SQL-Server syntax and I cannot test, if this works with Oracle too, but I think it will. You can use `XQuery` function `contains()`:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
<abcTenderItem>test1</abcTenderItem>
<SomeOther>should not show up</SomeOther>
<xyzTenderItem>test2</xyzTenderItem>
</root>';

SELECT @xml.query(N'/root/*[contains(local-name(),"TenderItem")]')
```

only the elements with "TenderItem" in their names show up:

```
<abcTenderItem>test1</abcTenderItem>
<xyzTenderItem>test2</xyzTenderItem>
```